# Как сделать чтоб повторное нажатие кнопки убирало контент?

Tags: jquery

Есть код

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("#div").load("https://site.ru/test.php");
})
});
</script>
<div id="div"><h2>Dynamic chart</h2></div>
<button>Get Dynamic chart</button>
```

Кнопкой подгружается контент взятый из ссылки.

1. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопка меняла название "Get Dynamic
   chart" на "Close Dynamic chart"
   и повторным нажатием контент исчезал.
2. Плюс если существует возможность при закрытии контента полученные
   ранее данные не хранились (javascript, css), которые находятся
   внутри файла test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let loaded = false; // Индикатор загруженного графика
  let originalContent = $("#div").html(); // Заглушка графика

  $("button").click(function() {
    if (loaded) {
      $("#div").html(originalContent);
      loaded = false;
      this.innerText = 'Get Dynamic chart';
    } else {
      this.disabled = true; // Исключаем возможность повторных запросов
      $.get("https://stackoverflow.getsandbox.com:443/dashboard", function(html) {
        $("#div").html(html);
        $("button").prop('disabled', false).text('Close Dynamic chart');
        loaded = true;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <h2>Dynamic chart</h2>
</div>
<button>Get Dynamic chart</button>
```

Comment: Кнопка работает, но после нажатия почему-то не меняет название и неактивна

Comment: Разобрался. После нажатия кнопки, подгружается контент и для того чтобы кнопка стала активна было необходима так же вставить ссылку на jquery в страницу get запроса. Почему-то без этого jquery перестает работать то-бишь кнопка обратно не работает

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как кнопке классприсвавать (объявлять)?